# gradle rebuilds projects even if no changes

Tags: android, gradle

I see that gradle often builds project even if I touched **no one** line of code, when I just restarting application.

How can I see what is the reason, why rebuilding happened?

Here is my gradle.properties

```
#Gradle configuration
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
android.enableBuildCache=true
```

Some more facts:

```
Gradle v.2.14.1
androidMinSdkVersion = 16
androidTargetSdkVersion = 24
androidCompileSdkVersion = 24
```

Comment: What does your gradle build script look like?

Comment: What is your gradle wrapper version?

Comment: @azizbekian, 2.14.1

Comment: @Alexey, is your minSdk version lower than 21?

Comment: @HuskyHuskie, I have 7 modules (1 Android application, 3 Android libraries and  3 Java libraries), so there are 7 scripts + one script for project

Comment: @Alexey can you show us those scripts?

Comment: @azizbekian, minSdk is 16. Have updated post with additional facts.

Comment: It seems to me that enableBuildCache doesn't work for minSdk lower 21. See [similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223688)

Comment: It really depends on what your doing in your scripts... for example if your scripts add a task with an input field containing `System.currentTimeMillis()` then your task might never be up to date.  If that task touches other files it could trigger more task to be out of date.  Run the build with `-i` to see why the up to date check fails when it should pass

Comment: @HuskyHuskie, not sure it's possible. The scripts are large and a bit dirty. Actually I need just get know **how to see** a reason, why gradle decides to rebuild, if all files are up to date.

Comment: Annotation Processors can force a rebuild, certain configurations can force a rebuild.

Comment: Well, may be... I use Dagger, Retrofit, Butterknife and greenrobot's EventBus.